# How to count total hour in fastapi?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I'm trying to count total of work hour and add up `is_overtime` number but I don't know how to do it.

My code so far:

Modles:

```
class Workhour(IdMixin, Base, TimestampMixin):

    __tablename__ = "workhour"

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    task_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("task.id"))
    date = Column(Date)
    hour = Column(Numeric(4,2))
    is_overtime = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    description = Column(String(255), index=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="workhours", uselist=False)
    task = relationship("Task", back_populates="workhours", uselist=False)
```

crud.py

```
def get_totalworkhours_by_user_id(db: Session, user_id: int, skip: int = 0):
    return db.query(models.Workhour.hour).filter(models.Workhour.user_id == user_id).offset(skip).count()
```

schemas.py

```
class WorkhourBase(BaseModel):
    user_id: Optional[int] = None
    task_id: int
    date: datetime.date
    hour: float
    description: Optional[str] = None
    is_overtime: Optional[bool] = False

class Workhour(WorkhourBase):
    id: int
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class WorkhourFull(Workhour):
    user: Optional[User]
    task: Optional[Task]
```

api/workhour.py

```
@router.get("/totalhour", response_model=schemas.WorkhourFull)
def read_totalworkhours(skip: int=0, user_id: int = None, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if user_id:
        totalworkhours = crud.get_totalworkhours_by_user_id(db, skip=skip, user_id=user_id)
    return totalworkhours
```

Comment: Change the `response_model` in the router decorator

Comment: This is probably more of an sqlalchemy question than a FastAPI question, but something like `db.query(func.sum(Score.score).label("hours_worked")).filter(models.Workhour.user_id == user_id).first()` should give you the total number of hours worked for that particular user id. `func` can be imported from `sqlalchemy.sql` - `from sqlalchemy.sql import func`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you very much!! It's exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

his is probably more of an sqlalchemy question than a FastAPI question, but something like:

```
db.query(func.sum(Score.score)\
    .label("hours_worked"))\
    .filter(models.Workhour.user_id == user_id)\
    .first()
```

should give you the total number of hours worked for that particular user id. `func` can be imported from `sqlalchemy.sql`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
```